# Streaming S3 upload with generated data

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am generating a large file in Python from an asynchronous queue that transforms many units of data and appends them (unordered) into a large file.

The final destination of this file is S3. To save I/O and dead time (wait for file to be complete before uploading), I would like to avoid writing the file to local disk first, and just stream the data to S3 as they are generated.

The units are all of different size but I can specify a reasonable max chunk size that is larger than any unit.

Most of the examples I see on the Web (e.g. https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/aws-s3-multipart-upload-download-using-boto3-python-sdk-2dedb0945f11) describe how to do a multi-part upload with boto3 from a file, not from data generated at runtime.

Is this possible, and a recommended approach?

EDIT: I removed the "multi-part" term from the title because I realized it could be misleading. What I really need is serial streaming of data chunks.

Thanks.

Comment: It's awkward that I tagged the post "s3" and it became "amazon-s3" complete with branding. Actually at the moment I am testing on a local S3 server that has nothing to do with AWS...

Answer (score 1):

The `upload()` method of the `MultipartUploadPart` object accepts a parameter `Body` that can either be a *file-like object* or a *bytes* object, which is what you want.

Take a look at [the documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.MultipartUploadPart.upload).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately that won't work for me because it requires to number the parts (1 to 10000 max) and each part must be at least 5Mb. I have millions of units, 2-4Kb each; assembling them to fit the API requirements would be complicated.

Comment: @user3758232 OK, it seems to be a limitation of the multipart uploading process in general, not specific to uploading a buffer instead of uploading a file.

Answer (score 0):

(Answering the updated question of *streaming* vs *uploading a file*)

I don't think it is possible to start an upload for a completely unknown amount of data (*streaming*).

All the upload functions either take *bytes* or a *seekable file-like-object* (see the [documentation for S3.object.put()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.put). This is most likely because they need to know the size of the data prior to actually transmitting it.

You could however consider saving each result as a single object in S3 and assembling it into one large file only when downloading it. But that would require a special programm to download the data and it might also increase the costs due to a higher number of requests and objects.

Comment: That's not doable in my case, where the effort to assemble a single file from millions of units would be repeated for every download.

Comment: @user3758232 Another solution would be to upload a single objects and let some AWS lambda assemble the large file.

Comment: @user3758232 Or you could take a look at Amazon-EFS, where you have actual files that you can append on.